# CampaignMember fields and unlocked packages

Tags: campaign-member, unlocked-package

I can't for the life of me figure out whether CampaignMember fields and the object are supported in 2nd Gen packages.  There's nothing in the Metadata Coverage Report on this object and I can't see anything on it either in the SOAP API documentation for this object.  Is that junction object not supported in any way for packaged metadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can retrieve, deploy, and package CampaignMember fields. However, StandardValueSet is not yet supported, except for managed packages. You can get your custom fields with this command:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject:CampaignMember
```

Comment: Thanks for that mate!  I did not know of the CustomObject:CampaignMember notation